# MessageHandlingException on a filter when using spring-integration 5.1.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-integration

So I'm trying to run a test that runs through the following flow:

```
@EnableBinding({Sink.class,Source.class})
public class MyFlow {
public @Bean IntegrationFlow myIntegrationFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows.from("input") //
  .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer()) //
  .filter(new MessageDroolsFilter())
  .........
  get();
}

 public class MessageDroolsFilter implements MessageSelector {

   @Override
   public boolean accept(Message<?> message) {
     return true;
   }

 }
}
```

So in `spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE` everything runs fine. 
I want to upgrade to `5.1.3.RELEASE` and I get the following exception. I can't see why it impacts the flow.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException:
 nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:
 Method call: Method accept(com.example.MyClass) 
cannot be found on type com.example.myIntegrationFlow$$Lambda$942/1009480482, failedMessage=GenericMessage
[payload=com.example.MyClasst@72bd8702[id=100, timestamp=1563801840597}]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.filter.AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.accept(AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter$Recipient.accept(RecipientListRouter.java:320)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter.lambda$determineTargetChannels$0(RecipientListRouter.java:258)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
```

Edit:

I have a router and I want route messages based on type of the object received.

```
private IntegrationFlow messagesFlow() {
  return sf -> sf //
      .routeToRecipients(routeMessages());
} 


private Consumer<RecipientListRouterSpec> routeMessages() {
  return sf -> sf
      .recipientFlow(new GenericSelector<MyObject1>() {

      @Override
      public boolean accept(MyObject1 source) {
        return source instanceof MyObject1;
      }},
        f -> f.transform(myTransformer)
              .filter(new DiscardHeaderMessageFilter()) 
              .handle(myHandler))
    .recipientFlow(new GenericSelector<MyObject2>() {
      @Override
      public boolean accept(MyObject2 source) {
        return source instanceof MyObject2;
      }
    }
    .defaultOutputChannel(DISCARD_CHANNEL);
}
```

I still get the same error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method accept(com.example.MyObject1) cannot be found on type com.example.MyFlow$2
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:225)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:134)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:390)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:365)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:172)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:664)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:655)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:491)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:362)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:106)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like your problem is related to the mentioned `.filter()`.

See stack trace carefully:

```
at org.springframework.integration.filter.AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.accept(AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.java:62)
at org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter$Recipient.accept(RecipientListRouter.java:320)
```

So, you have a `routeToRecipients()` somewhere and one of its `recipient()` doesn't fit  expectations.

**UPDATE**

The error is expectable: a Recipient List Router consults with each recipient against the current message. When your message is `MyObject1`, the first one, `.recipientFlow(new GenericSelector<MyObject1>()`, works well because its method signature is compatible with object you call it. But when the same `MyObject1` reaches the second one - `.recipientFlow(new GenericSelector<MyObject2>()` -, it can't call it because non-compatible type.

Fully unclear why would one does `source instanceof MyObject1;` in the method when argument is exactly `MyObject1`...

I would say that signature must be like this:

```
.recipientFlow(new GenericSelector<Object>() {

  @Override
  public boolean accept(Object source) {
    return source instanceof MyObject1;
  }}
```

I mean generic `Object` type compatible with any payload sent. It's fully unclear why your IDE didn't tell you that `source instanceof MyObject2` is redundant since it is going always be `true`, when this method is called. Only the problem that this method fails against any other type when we call it via reflection, like in that case with SpEL.

Comment: Yes, thank you,  you are right, I have updated the original question, still get an error

Comment: Please, take a look into an UPDATE in my answer.